# Sensu Check for Long running MySQL Queries.

Tags: mysql

I need to build a test / checker ( ruby, python, bash , your personal pref) that will check for long running queries every few minutes. It will incorporate with sensu, and then alarm if the threshold is met. Sensu will be able to alarm ( or I can set up custom slack notifications )

Honestly I am not even sure where to start. I am really looking for how you guys would approach this issue.  any help would be great!

I can provide a sample of what I used to test other things

Comment: You may start with `show processlist`

Comment: Yea. I was thinking that. I'm guessing that I can pull in that data, and then store it, and check it in a loop? I think I figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On Sensu-client side...please install some of below dependencies...

gem install mysql
gem install inifile
gem install cli

```
1.check-mysql-alive.rb 
2.check-mysql-connections.rb 
3.check-mysql-disk.rb
4.check-mysql-replication-status.rb


  {
      "client": {
        "name": "servername.sensu.org",
        "address": "IPADDRESS",
        "subscriptions": ["all","mysql"],
        "database": {
         "DiskSize": "200G",
         "SizeWarningThreshold": "85",
         "SizeCriticalThreshold": "95",
         "ReplicationLagWarningThreshold": "900",
         "ReplicationLagCriticalThreshold": "1800",
         "name": "mysqldb"
        },
        "connection": {
         "warnnum": "10",
         "critnum": "22"
        }
      }
    }
```

and rest you will get on my [github-link](https://github.com/venoodkhatuva12/sensu-plugins-mysql)..